# Clarification for Newton's Third Law of Motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

I feel like I'm correct, but I don't know for sure.

When you squat, you're exerting force on the ground. And when you explode into the air, the ground is exerting the equal and opposite force, right?

Comment: ..what? Like, really, what do you mean? While you squad, there is a force from Earth towards you (known as gravity) acting on both bodies, as well as the normal forces, again on both bodies. And when you explode into air, the same process happens. What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: @acarturk I could be wrong, but I believe the question is asking if  pushing the earth with X Newton’s of force also means the earth pushes oppositely with a force of X Newtons. It’s probably a confusion resulting from the apparent large differences in mass in the two bodies in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're standing, you're going to be exerting some force on the ground, and the ground will exert the opposite back, or else you would accelerate right through the ground.

When you squat, you're actually temporarily reducing the force between you and the ground, so you're exerting *less* force than when you were standing still.  You should be able to feel the weight on your feet decrease when you move for the squat.  It's because you are accelerating towards the ground slightly, so the ground has to counteract gravity less than completely as you let acceleration due to gravity bring you into the squat.

When going back up, the opposite occurs, and the force between you and the ground increases.  This allows you to accelerate against gravity, and bring your centre of mass back up to standing height.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'when you explode into the air' you mean 'when you jumo' then yes. When you jump, you exert a force on the ground and the ground exerts a force of the same magnitude on your feet.